# GoLang workspace, папки bin, pkg, src

Tags: golang

Несколько месяцев назад начал изучать Go. Вроде разобрался с пакетами и импортами(возможно я так думал).
У меня структура как по гайду:
GoProjects:
    -bin
    -src
    -pkg
В папке src мои проекты, потом есть еще папки github.com, golang.org, gopkg.in(есть ли объяснение вторым двум папкам?). Насчет папки github.com все ясно, там лежат чужие исходники, которые я скачал(но там лежат не понятные мне karrick, mdempsky, pkg, sqs и тд), что приводят меня в удивление, так как у меня плохая память, но я сомневаюсь, что я больше одного раза попытался сделать go get с github, ибо я не особо еще понимаю, как импортировать чужой код для своего проекта(единственная попытка не получилась, я не смог использовать адекватно код скачанного пакета, а точнее import то-ли не видел его, толи я что-то не так делал и очень все мутно объясняется).
Что если я удалю эти папки?
Только что почитал про это все, создал в проекте .go файл, запустил. Открыл bin, там этого файла нет, сделал go build, .exe появился в проекте. Тогда зачем bin? что именно туда залетает? сейчас там какие-то .exe есть:
autobahn, command, filewatch, go_build_main_go, gocode, gopkgs, goreturns, chat(это возможно, если мне память не изменияет, я делал чат на сокетах(хотел сравнить с java), и вроде как получилось туда запихнуть .exe, хотя возможно я ошибаюсь и никакого отношения не имею к этому chat.exe (опять так вопрос, что если я удалю все эти .exe`шники?). В папке pkg 2 папки: mod, windows_amd64(amd? у меня intel, ладно в низкоуровневом я не разбираюсь, возможно я глупость спросил).
Или у меня тут все нормально и мне не нужно заморачиваться с этим всем и спокойно обучаться используя src/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `${GOPATH}/src/` лежат исходники. Если вы сделали `go get`, то он загрузит как пакет, который вам нужен, так и все его зависимости, рекурсивно, потому что иначе проект не собрать.

В `${GOPATH}/bin/` появляются исполняемые файлы, которые вы установили с помощью `go install` или `go get`. `go build` по умолчанию кладёт в `$PWD`, но это можно изменить флагом `-o`.

В `${GOPATH}/pkg/` лежат скомпилированные пакеты, а также кеш модулей. Поддиректории — платформы и опции компиляции. `amd64` — общепринятое название 64-битной интеловской архитектуры.

Comment: спасибо, вроде понятней стало)

Comment: @ekstra777 Пожалуйста. Если ответ вас устраивает, проголосуйте за него, нажав стрелку вверх, и отметьте его как верный, нажав галочку.

Comment: мой голос не отображается, из-за репутации